# Is there a preferred way to design signal or event APIs in Go?

Tags: go

I am designing a package where I want to provide an API based on the observer pattern: that is, there are points where I'd like to emit a signal that will trigger zero or more interested parties.  Those interested parties shouldn't necessarily need to know about each other.

I know I can implement an API like this from scratch (e.g. using a collection of channels or callback functions), but was wondering if there was a preferred way of structuring such APIs.

In many of the languages or frameworks I've played with, there has been standard ways to build these APIs so that they behave the way users expect: e.g. the `g_signal_*` functions for glib based applications, events and `addEventListener()` for JavaScript DOM apps, or multicast delegates for .NET.

Is there anything similar for Go?  If not, is there some other way of structuring this type of API that is more idiomatic in Go?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would say that a goroutine receiving from a channel is an analogue of an observer to a certain extent. An idiomatic way to expose events in Go would be thus IMHO to return channels from a package (function). Another observation is that callbacks are not used too often in Go programs. One of the reasons is also the existence of the powerful [`select statement`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements).

As a final note: some people (me too) consider GoF patterns as Go antipatterns.

Comment: I think this answer covers some use cases, but I'd definitely like to hear more opinions/answers about this. Channels put a little more burden on the caller (the "observer"), as it has to start a goroutine that waits on this channel. If the same function can handle many "events", this can become cumbersome. As a counter-example, callbacks are used in net/http for HTTP handlers. There are use cases where they make more sense IMHO.

Comment: I only used the term "observer pattern" since it is a term people might understand: I don't write my programs by first breaking them down into named design patterns, if that's what you were getting at.  As far as your API suggestion, I can see how a function returning read-side channels could work for the subscription side, but how would you model the matching unsubscribe API?

Comment: Channels are comparable for equality and they are first class objects.  To unsubscribe, just pass the channel back to the publishier, it can find its record of the channel and take appropriate action to terminate the subscription.

Answer (score 5):

I needed an "observer pattern" type thing in a couple of projects.  [Here's a reusable example](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/cbgb/blob/master/broadcaster.go) from a recent project.

It's got a corresponding test that shows how to use it.

The basic theory is that an event emitter calls `Submit` with some piece of data whenever something interesting occurs.  Any client that wants to be aware of that event will `Register` a channel it reads the event data off of.  This channel you registered can be used in a `select` loop, or you can read it directly (or buffer and poll it).

When you're done, you `Unregister`.

It's not perfect for *all* cases (e.g. I may want a force-unregister type of event for slow observers), but it works where I use it.

Answer (score 4):

Go gives you a lot of tools for designing a signal api.

First you have to decide a few things:

Do you want a push or a pull model? eg. Does the publisher push events to the subscribers or do the subscribers pull events from the publisher?

If you want a push system then having the subscribers give the publisher a channel to send messages on would work really well. If you want a pull method then just a message box guarded with a mutex would work. Other than that without knowing more about your requirements it's hard to give much more detail.

Comment: For my particular use case, it would be the publisher broadcasting the events and subscribers reacting as soon as possible.  It's a case where interactivity would be more important than throughput, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I would say there is no standard way of doing this because channels are built into the language.  There is no channel library with standard ways of doing things with channels, there are simply channels.  Having channels as built in first class objects frees you from having to work with standard techniques and lets you solve problems in the simplest most natural way.

Comment: I know about channels (I even mentioned them in the question).  But channels really only offer a 1-1 communication mechanism, while I want 1-many (where many might be zero).  So I can't really make the API channels and nothing else.

Comment: Not true at all.  Channels can have multiple senders and multiple receivers.  Anyway, you might as well complain that variables are no good because they can only hold one value at a time.  Need more?  Use a data structure.  A publisher can store all of its subscribers in a slice, a map, a tree structure, whatever makes sense in your case.  To publish, iterate over the data structure and send the update to each subscriber.

Comment: I was referring to channels as being 1-1 in the sense that for each message, the channel connects one sender to one receiver.  While you can certainly use multiple receivers to e.g. divide work between goroutines, that is clearly not what I was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic Golang version of Node EventEmitter at https://github.com/chuckpreslar/emission

See http://itjumpstart.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/eventemitter-in-go/